# Mongoose populate not getting any value after populating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

Hi im building mern project which have a social media feature, this social media have profile, post, and comment. I want to populate profile model to post model, so that i know which post belongs to which user. But im having a problem using populate, its not working the field that have ref is removed after populating.

idk why this happend can someone tell me whats wrong with the code. Thanks.

Models :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755260290450587661/1052037045607997472/image.png

SosmedPost.js model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const SosmedPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   Username : {
        type : String
   }, 
   Content : {
        type : String
   },
   Documents : {
        type : String
   },
   Author : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'sosmedprofiles'}
}, {timestamps : true});


const SosmedPostModel = mongoose.model('sosmedposts', SosmedPostSchema);
module.exports = SosmedPostModel;
```

SosmedProfile models

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const SosmedProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

       _id : {
         type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
       },
       Username : {
            type : String
       },
       FullName : {
            type : String
       },
       ProfilePicture : {
            type : String
       },
       Bio : {
            type : String
       },
       Post : { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'sosmedposts'}
    }, {timestamps : true});
    
    
    const SosmedProfileModel = mongoose.model('sosmedprofiles', SosmedProfileSchema);
    module.exports = SosmedProfileModel
```

route / controllers for Sosmed Post

```
const getPostById = async (req, res) => {
   const Id = req.params.id;

   SosmedPostModel.findOne({_id : Id})
   .populate("Author")
   .exec(function (err, posts) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(posts);
      res.send(posts)
   })
}
```

Result :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/755260290450587661/1052037628016476170/image.png

Update :

```
const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  
  if (req.file) {
    const Post = new SosmedPostModel({
      Username : req.body.Username,
      Title : req.body.Title,
      Content : req.body.Content,
      Documents : `https://bsi-portal-service-production.up.railway.app/images/${req.file.filename}`
    })
    await Post.save();
    res.send(Post);
  } else {
    const Post = new SosmedPostModel({
      Username : req.body.Username,
      Title : req.body.Title,
      Content : req.body.Content
    })
    await Post.save();
    res.send(Post);
  }
}
```

Comment: The query looks good, can you post the code where you are inserting a new `sosmedposts` into the database?

Comment: @lpizzinidev i already update the code

Comment: You posted the front-end, I meant the API endpoint

Comment: @lpizzinidev you can check now

Comment: You should set the `Author` identifier as well, otherwise, it won't know with what `ref` to populate.

Comment: @lpizzinidev the author body value should be the id of the profile sosmed yes ?

Comment: Yes, correct...